# What is the Android Best approach to write logs after deployment?

Tags: android, logging

I am working on android project and have to write a logging system that will record everything happening in the app during production.

What is the best way to do this? I was thinking about writing my own simple writeToFile class but then I see some people use Logging libraries.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514175/which-android-logging-framework-to-use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of libraries to log the data. One of the most popular and simple library that i came across is "Hugo" developed by Jake Wharton. Its simple easy to use and flexible.
You can find the link to the library here https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo