# Android tool for logging in production

Tags: android

We are releasing an App that depends on some tricky external factors (like BluetoothLE chip, GPS satellites reception, activity recognition, and so on…) so we need to be able to follow tightly our first hundred of clients in order to understand how they use it and what kind of issue they encounter.

So far out best bet is to gather logs from the app: hopefully sending live logcat to a server will help us find out ***what is happening*** on each phone.

I'm looking for advices here : is remote-logging a good practice for this need (*seeing what happens on the phone*) ? If yes, is there any good tools for this ?

Please note that we are not in the scope of a crash reporting tool… (that we already implement).

Thank you for your advised experience tips :)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should not upload logs from device to server, because there would be so many devices and frequency of log generation is so high, so it would eat up battery and network of user's device if you upload logs continuously on server.

But if you want to do it, you can do it in following ways:

1. Use any logger library: [logging frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514175/which-android-logging-framework-to-use), 

2. Get logs and upload it to server.

Comment: Thank you for this link ! Indeed you're right it could become huge - that's why it will be limited to our first reak-world testers and ideally WE Will trigger this logging feature on demande with push command fir example. Otherwise if there are other good methods to understand what is happening on the phone I'll be glad to hear about it of course :)